# Auto select correspondance radion in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I have Dynamic radio in one div LIke Here the name of radio is dynamic and value also :

```
<input type="radio" name="first[1]" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="first[2]" value="2" />
<input type="radio" name="first[3]" value="3" />


And the second div I have which have these radios : 

<input type="radio" name="second[1]" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="second[2]" value="2" />
<input type="radio" name="second[3]" value="3" />
```

> My question is that if I checked (yes) the div first radio button
>   then div second radio is selected auto.  It's like both div radio
>   working together on check fo yes and no both condition.

I try this to get the val of first div but here I'm not getting the value ..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
alert('ok');
$('input:radio').on('click',function() { 
var obj=$('input[name="first"]:checked').val();
alert(obj);
});
});
</script>


Can any one please help me related this?
```

Giving Some extra info like :

Comment: Is there any solution ???

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var first = $('input[name^=first]');
    var second = $('input[name^=second]');
    first.change(function(){
        var index = $(this).index();
        if(this.checked){
            second.eq(index).prop('checked', true);
        }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Ur code is not working in my case... see my updated question

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Add your javascript here
$(function() {
  $('input[name^="first"],input[name^="second"]').on('change', function() {

    let i = $(this).index();
    $('input[name^="first"]').each(function(j) {
      $(this).prop('checked', i === j);
    });
    $('input[name^="second"]').each(function(j) {
      $(this).prop('checked', i === j);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="first[1]" value="1" />A
  <input type="radio" name="first[2]" value="2" />B
  <input type="radio" name="first[3]" value="3" />C
</div>


<div>
  <input type="radio" name="second[1]" value="1" />AA
  <input type="radio" name="second[2]" value="2" />BB
  <input type="radio" name="second[3]" value="3" />CC
</div>
```

Comment: In ur code when u added alert its showing but in my case that alert is not working why ...

Comment: you have this line `$('input[name="first"]:checked').val();` but none of your input element has name equals to first... you have one with name equals to "first[1]", anothe with name equals to "first[2]" and another with name equals to "first[3]", so with the selector 'input[name="first":checked' this doenst bring anything, with the selector that he used: 'input[name^="first" look for any input with name that has "first" on it